# Why is the return type reference to output stream?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-type, ostream

I am new to C++ and learning operator overloading. Now in the followng code, I get everything except little bit confused as to **why the return type is reference to output stream?**

We have the following enum.

```
enum days{ SON, SAT, MON, TUE, WED, THRUS, FRI };
```

And we are overloading `<<` operator , to print the days instead of the numerical value 0, 1, 2 ... and so on.

The code is:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream &,const days &d)
{
 switch(d)
 {
  case SUN: out << "SUN"; break;
  case MON: out << "MON"; break;
  case TUE: out << "TUE"; break;
  case WED: out << "WED"; break;
  .....
  ... 
 }
 return out;
}
```

Comment: What else should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ostream class has overloaded the insertion operator (<<) for many types of data; int, char, char*, string...

- the return type of this operator is a reference to an ostream object so when you call it; you can use the return type to print another stuff and the return type of printing this stuff is a reference to an ostream object which you can use it to print another stuff and so on...
- when you write:

  ```
  cout << 1 << "Hello" << 2.7 << endl;
  ```

at the beginning cout prints 1 and returns us an ostream object we use it to print "Hello" (calling <<(ostream&, char*)) and returns again a reference to an ostream object so we use it to print 2.7 and so on...

- the line above can be translated as:

  ```
  (((cout << 1) << "Hello") << 2.7) << endl;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

> why the return type is reference to output stream?

Returning `ostream&` making it possible to chain it, like

```
std::cout << SON << SAT << MON << TUE << WED << THRUS << FRI;
```

BTW: [Output stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) is not supposed to (and can't) be copied, so return type is reference (instead of by value).